# Unable to understand an integration substitution trick

Tags: integration, substitution

I am learning basic calculus, and have learnt how to substitute terms in integrals to make it easier to work with (let $u=f(x)$, then $dx=\frac{du}{f'(x)}$). During classes, our lecturer presented something like the following steps repeatedly without explaining how it works, and my not-so-bright brain just can't figure out what is happening. Here's a basic example:

$$\int \sqrt x \ln x dx$$
$$=\int \ln x d(\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}})$$

I figured out that $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}} = \sqrt x$, but why does this work? What am I substituting (what is $f(x)$ substituted as $u$)? When it's used in a definite integral, how do I change the two bounds?

Comment: Oh! So $u$ is substituting $\frac{2}{3} x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ which comes from $\int \sqrt x dx$?And I can just change the bounds like I normally do, substituting the two bounds into $u$ for a new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int\sqrt{x}\ln{(x)}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int\ln{(x)}\mathrm{d}u\qquad(u=\frac23x^{3/2},\quad\mathrm{d}u=\sqrt{x}\mathrm{d}x)\\
&=\int\frac23\ln{\left(\frac32u\right)}\mathrm{d}u\\
\end{align}